# Add some integers to a multiset so that $\sum\arctan\frac1x=\frac\pi2$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, generating-functions

> $S$ is a finite multiset of positive integers for which $\displaystyle\sum_{x\in S}\arctan\frac1x<\frac\pi2$. Show there $\exists S’,S\subset S’\displaystyle\sum_{x\in S’}\arctan\frac1x=\frac\pi2$.

Let $S=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$. We add $b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_t$ to $S$ to form $S’$. For each item $s$ in $S’$ we construct a corresponding complex number $s+i$ because $\arg(s+i)=\arctan\frac1s$.

Using complex number property can get $\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^n(a_k+i)\prod_{j=1}^t(b_j+i)\in i\mathbb R$. Perhaps this is now a polynomial problem: the sum of coefficients of terms with exponent $\equiv2\pmod4$ and $\equiv0\pmod4$ are the same.

Comment: "$S$ is a finite group"? Did you mean "set"? or which operation are you considering on $S$?

Comment: Just to check, we are only supposed to add a finite set of integers to $S$, right? Because it should be easy if you allow infinite sums. Nice problem!

Comment: If you add something to $S$ then it is no longer $S$. You should use a different symbol.

Comment: @jjagmath I just want to show that items in $S$ are not necessarily different and otherwise it is just like a set.

Comment: Oh, so $S$ is a multiset? Or sequence, maybe.

Comment: @youthdoo Ok, but then don't use the word "group" that already has a [standard meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)) in Mathematics

Comment: If elements may appear multiple times, then a set cannot represent this because, say $\{1,2,2\} = \{1,2\}$. So better use a tuple or [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset).

Comment: I have a sense of deja vu... Is this related to the fact that you can always get 1 as sum of $1/a_i$ with integer positive $a_i$, starting from any fraction?

Comment: The basic strategies of the proof are similar: We want to show that any positive $\tfrac{b}{a}$ can be written as $\sum \tfrac{1}{q_i}$, or we want to show that any positive $\tan^{-1} \tfrac{b}{a}$ can be written as $\sum \tan^{-1} \tfrac{1}{q_i}$. In both cases, the strategy is to choose $q$ such that $b > bq-a \geq a$. Then we have $\tfrac{b}{a} - \tfrac{1}{q} = \tfrac{bq-a}{a}$ or $\tan^{-1} \tfrac{b}{a} - \tan^{-1}  \tfrac{1}{q} =\tan^{-1}  \tfrac{bq-a}{aq+b}$ respectively, and we induct on the numerator.

Comment: Sorry, that should be $bq-a \geq 0$, not $\geq a$. But I don't feel like deleting and typing again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the formula $\tan(x+y)=(\tan x+\tan y)/(1-\tan x\tan y)$, it is not difficult to check that the sum of $\arctan1/x$ is $\arctan a/b$ with positive integers $a,b$. Adding many $\arctan1/M$ with large $M$, we can reach $a>b$. Now, we have
$$
 \arctan\frac ab+\arctan\frac 1N=\arctan\frac{\frac ab+\frac 1N}{1-\frac{a}{Nb}}=\arctan\frac{Na+b}{Nb-a}.
$$
Choosing the first $N$ such that $Nb-a>0$, we obtain
$$
 \arctan\frac ab+\arctan\frac 1N=\arctan\frac{a_1}{b_1},\ \ \ b_1<b.
$$
Repeating this procedure we arrive at the case $b_k=1$. Thus, the sum of all $\arctan$ in the new set is $\arctan A$ with some positive integer $A$. Finally,
$$
 \arctan A+\arctan \frac1A=\frac\pi2.
$$